# Error: @vitejs/plugin-vue requires vue (>=3.2.13) or @vue/compiler-sfc to be present in the dependency tree

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, yarn-workspaces, webpack-module-federation

I'm working with the berry version of yarn with modules federation and vue3.
When I run these commands to create the base of the project:

```
mkdir vue-error
yarn set version stable
yarn plugin import workspace-tools
yarn init -pw
cd packages
npx create-mf-app # body
yarn
yarn workspace body add single-spa-vue
cd body
yarn start
```

I get the following error:

```
[webpack-cli] Failed to load '/Users/test/Development/trash/vue-error/packages/body/webpack.config.js' config
[webpack-cli] Error: @vitejs/plugin-vue requires vue (>=3.2.13) or @vue/compiler-sfc to be present in the dependency tree.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jcuzmar/Development/trash/vue-error/.yarn/__virtual__/vue-loader-virtual-8ff7836f4c/0/cache/vue-loader-npm-16.8.3-e05f7daca3-7c0566847b.zip/node_modules/vue-loader/dist/compiler.js:14:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.external_module_.Module._load (/Users/jcuzmar/Development/trash/vue-error/.pnp.cjs:17959:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jcuzmar/Development/trash/vue-error/.yarn/__virtual__/vue-loader-virtual-8ff7836f4c/0/cache/vue-loader-npm-16.8.3-e05f7daca3-7c0566847b.zip/node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js:8:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
```

I tried adding:

```
packageExtensions:
  "@vitejs/plugin-vue@*":
    peerDependencies:
      'vue': '*'
      '@vue/compiler-sfc': '*'
      webpack: '*'
```

without success.

Answer (score 24):

Upgrading `vue` to the latest available version solved the issue for me :)

If you’re using Yarn:

```
yarn add vue@3.2.26
```

If you’re using NPM:

```
npm i vue@3.2.26
```

Any version equal or above 3.2.13 should take care of it.

Comment: I'm using vue 2, upgrading to vue 3 would break everything

Comment: I'm using vue 3.0.0 and using the above npm i command fix the problem with me. So the answer still stands

Comment: For others, it may require pinning to `3.2.26`, if you are on node 12.

Comment: @Shardj OP mentioned he's using Vue3.. If you're using vue2 and get this error, consider open a new SO question

Comment: @C.Bess That was my issue! Do you know why the error message says nothing about vue being incompatible with the node version?

Answer (score 3):

Another point is to check your node version and if any of your VUE based plugins or dependencies require a specific node version. Fixed a VUE build for me.

Answer (score 2):

Updating my node.js version helped resolve this issue.

I recommend installing [node version manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to allow you to very easily swap between node versions.

Answer (score 1):

"@vue/compat": "^3.2.29",
"vue": "^3.2.29",
"@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.29",

incase if you face this issue when you migrating. please

do

npm uninstall @vue/compiler-sfc

then

npm install @vue/compiler-sfc@3.2.29

it get fix.

Answer (score -2):

If you’re using NPM:

**npm i vue@3.2.26**